How to mount a fully encrypted disk using Ubuntu 24.04 usb at Dell XPS 9360?
TL; DR
How do I mount the rpool partition and copy the content into a removable drive?



gparted
ubuntu decryptor









Description
After a storm that caused a power surge, the UEFI is not being recognized and the Ubuntu 24.04 is not properly booting anymore.
Thus I wish move the encrypted content into a external SSD connected by USB, then wipeout the system and do a clean install.
The questions are:

How do I mount the rpool partition using the same paraphrase used by Ubuntu decryptor?
How do I move into external SSD? (copy or rsync -avz)?

